# Binding an event to an element that has so many element inside it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this kind of html

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li class="page_leftArrow ${indexOfCurrentPage == 0 ? "disabled" : ""}">
  <a href="#" aria-label="Previous" class="arrowPage left">
    <span aria-hidden="true"><i class="icon-arrows-left" max="${max}"></i></span>
  </a>
</li>
```

Now I need to bind an event if this "li" is clicked. But if you will notice, inside the li, there is link and inside a link there is an icon. If I happen to press on the area of icon, i get a different element which is not good in the system that I'm doing. Example, I need to get the class in the li, If I clicked on the area of link, I will I get "arrowPage left" instead of ""page_leftArrow

My question is what can I do so that when I click on the inside of "li", I will get the correct element.

Comment: I'm not clear what your asking

Comment: @Liam example in the html that I posted, I bind an event wherein i will let the user see the class of an element he just clicked. alert($(event.target).attr("class")); Since iinside "li". I have "a" and "i"  element, if clicked in the area of "i", The system will show the classes in "i". However when I clicked in the area of "a" I get the classes in "a". The correct behavior should be getting the classes of "li" right? Was I able to explain it clearer this time?

Comment: It's better to update the question, not add details in comments

Comment: show the classes? I don't know what this means

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hope to understand the question right. Lets separate your questions. First you need to bind click event on the `li`. So the code will go like this

```
$('.page_leftArrow').on('click', function() {
  //here is your code.
});
```

you have to know that like `$(this)` selector, in the event, you can take current clicked `<li>` tag and from there you can make your logic. Also if you make the link like this `<a href="javascript:void(0)" aria-label="Previous" class="arrowPage left">`. this kind of href will prevent the link from executing.